Finding Longest Palindromic Substring, solution is too inefficient but I am not convinced dp is more efficient in this case
I have a solution which is O(n^2).
My idea loop through each character of the given string and find longest possible odd and even substring which results in a palindrome.
Why does my solution take so much more time to compute than some dp answers which also have O(n^2) even though it seems to me that my solution does not repeat computations, since each character could have a unique even or odd palindrome.
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
        string palindrome = "";

        //checking for odd palindrome
        for (int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
            //current strings
            string curO = "";
            string curE = "";
            //since its for odd current string
            curO+=s[i];

            //indexes to check if palindrome can be exteneded 
            int leftO = i-1;
            int rightO = i+1;
            int leftE = i;
            int rightE = i+1;

            //incrementing based on finding odd palindrome
            while (leftO >= 0 && rightO < s.size() && s[leftO] == s[rightO]){
                curO = s[leftO] + curO + s[rightO];
                leftO--;
                rightO++;
            }

            //incrementing based on finding even palindrome
            while (leftE >=0 && rightE <s.size() && s[leftE] == s[rightE]){
                curE = s[leftE] + curE + s[rightE];
                leftE--;
                rightE++;
            }
            if (curO.size() > palindrome.size()) palindrome = curO;
            if (curE.size() > palindrome.size()) palindrome = curE;
        }

        return palindrome;
    }

